Server works when hosted on 127.0.0.1, but doesn't not work when testing it with a real ip. - C
This code works when using it locally(ip = 127.0.0.1), but doesn't work when testing it with a real ip.
It doesn't work when I host the server, nor when my friend hosts the server.
My friend suspects that it's a firewall issue, but we both have it inactive - I checked with sudo ufw status, he with sudo netstat -ntlp.
// client.c
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    int port = 8080;
    const char *ip = "127.0.0.1"; // Changed this to the real ip to test it.

    int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sock == -1) {
        return 2;
    }
    struct sockaddr_in hint;
    hint.sin_family = AF_INET;
    hint.sin_port = htons(port);
    inet_pton(AF_INET, ip, &hint.sin_addr);
    int connResult = connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&hint, sizeof(hint));
    if (connResult == -1) {
        int status = shutdown(sock, SHUT_RDWR);
        if (status == 0) {
            status = close(sock);
        }
        return status;
    }

    while (1) {
        const char *msg = "ping";
        int sendResult = send(sock, msg, strlen(msg) + 1, 0);
        if (sendResult == -1)
        {
            return 3;
        }
        usleep(1000 * 2000);
    }
    /* unreachable */
    int status = shutdown(sock, SHUT_RDWR);
    if (status == 0) {
        status = close(sock);
    }
    return status;
}

// server.c
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFF_SIZE 4096

int main() {
    int port = 8080;

    int status;
    while (1) {
        int listening = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        if (listening == -1) {
            return 1;
        }
        struct sockaddr_in hint;
        hint.sin_family = AF_INET;
        hint.sin_port = htons(port);
        hint.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
        if (bind(listening, (struct sockaddr *)&hint, sizeof(hint)) == -1){
            return 1;
        }
        listen(listening, SOMAXCONN);

        struct sockaddr_in client;
        unsigned int clientSize = sizeof(client);
        int clientSocket =
            accept(listening, (struct sockaddr *)&client, &clientSize);

        int status = 0;
        status = shutdown(listening, SHUT_RDWR);
        if (status == 0) {
            status = close(listening);
        }

        char buff[BUFF_SIZE];
        while (1) {
            memset(buff, 0, BUFF_SIZE);

            int bytesReceived = recv(clientSocket, buff, BUFF_SIZE, 0);
            if (bytesReceived == -1) {
                return 2;
            }
            if (bytesReceived > BUFF_SIZE) {
                return 3;
            }
            if (bytesReceived > 0) {
                printf("A client sent: %s\n", buff);
            } else {
                break;
            }
            usleep(1000 * 1000);
        }
        status = shutdown(clientSocket, SHUT_RDWR);
        if (status == 0) {
            status = close(clientSocket);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

Compile commands:
gcc server.c -o server
gcc client.c -o client


Run tcpdump / wireshark on both ends to ensure the packets are being received.

Dbush. Okay. My friend is not online right now. So I will test it later, and report back.

@CarlHR

Try changing the server ip address to 0.0.0.0, to accept all addresses,

I think this line does that?: hint.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;.

But, if the server is hidden behind a NAT interface.

I think that's the case, so I will start reading about NAT. Thanks!

If there's a NAT, you'll need to implement port forwarding.

Just know that, for using port fowarding, you need to own the router or have admin access to it.

@CarlHR Is there another way to connect that doesn't need admin access ? I thought peer-to-peer connections didn't need admin.

https://ngrok.com/ this service can be used that way.  Haven't used in a while but for all I know they still offer free proxying for services behind nat.    Not sure if they support generic TCP

Does hole punching also work for NAT ?

You need to confirm that it is listening on the address... netstat (with the appropriate flags for the OS variant you have) is needed.

@benc It seems that it is listening.
$ sudo netstat -ntlp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      63789/./server

So, if you are listening on 0.0.0.0 and you can connect locally on 127.0.0.1, but you can't connect locally to the interface IP, you have some kind of local config problem. You should double check your interface configs (ifconfig -a) and also look at your routing table (route -a or netstat -nr)... [note: specific commands vary by distro.]
